# Bluetooth in iOS - when to stop scanning if no peripherals found

Tags: ios, bluetooth, cbperipheralmanager

I'm using 'scanForPeripheralsWithServices' in iOS and successfully connecting to my intended device.

But Apple's documentation doesn't cover the case where no valid peripheral is found. What is the best practice for determining no peripherals are available, stopping the scan, and notify app users?

Comment: I didn't understand, what are you trying to achieve ? Stopping the scan or anything else ?

Comment: If a valid peripheral isn't found in a reasonable time window, I want to stop scanning and notify the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using a `NSTimer`. And from the Bluetooth scanning (initializing) function, schedule that timer too.

```
@implementation YourClass
{
   NSTimer *timer;
}
- (void)startScan
{
   // Bluetooth related code
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:25 target:self selector:@selector(stopScan) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

// Stops the Scanning and Timer
- (void)stopScan
{
   [yourCBCentralManager stopScan];
   [timer invalidate];
   timer = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Great. I added a boolean variable to monitor if my desired peripheral was found in that time interval.